# Issue with jquery datatables ajax datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I've followed the example shown on the datatables website for making an ajax request and I can't get it to work with the data tables nuget package. The model binder is mad because the search value is null and expects it to be an empty string.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult ListUsers([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest request)
```

View:

```
<table id="users-table" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').dataTable({
       ajax: '@Url.Action("ListUsers", "Businesses",null,Request.Url.Scheme)'
    });
});
```

The value of the search cannot be null. If there's no search performed, provide an empty string.
Parameter name: value

Comment: Are you sure you're expecting the [correct structure of request parameters](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters), especially `search[value]`?

Comment: I'm not expecting anything, the Nuget package and the jquery library work together with no custom code needed.

Comment: If you're using server-side processing, you need to add `'serverSide': true` DataTables parameter.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Server side was what I needed to use, not the ajax example found on the site. If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using server-side processing, you need to add `'serverSide': true` as DataTables parameter, see the code below:

```
$('#users-table').dataTable({
  'serverSide': true,
  'ajax': '@Url.Action("ListUsers", "Businesses",null,Request.Url.Scheme)'
});
```